# OutOfOrderScannerNextException when filtering results in HBase

Tags: java, filter, hbase

I am trying to filter results in HBase this way:

```
List<Filter> andFilterList = new ArrayList<>();
SingleColumnValueFilter sourceLowerFilter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("source"), CompareFilter.CompareOp.GREATER, Bytes.toBytes(lowerLimit));
sourceLowerFilter.setFilterIfMissing(true);
SingleColumnValueFilter sourceUpperFilter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("source"), CompareFilter.CompareOp.LESS_OR_EQUAL, Bytes.toBytes(upperLimit));
sourceUpperFilter.setFilterIfMissing(true);
SingleColumnValueFilter targetLowerFilter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("target"), CompareFilter.CompareOp.GREATER, Bytes.toBytes(lowerLimit));
targetLowerFilter.setFilterIfMissing(true);
SingleColumnValueFilter targetUpperFilter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("target"), CompareFilter.CompareOp.LESS_OR_EQUAL, Bytes.toBytes(upperLimit));
targetUpperFilter.setFilterIfMissing(true);

andFilterList.add(sourceUpperFilter);
andFilterList.add(targetUpperFilter);

FilterList andFilter = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL, andFilterList);

List<Filter> orFilterList = new ArrayList<>();
orFilterList.add(sourceLowerFilter);
orFilterList.add(targetLowerFilter);
FilterList orFilter = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ONE, orFilterList);

FilterList fl = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL);
fl.addFilter(andFilter);
fl.addFilter(orFilter);

Scan edgeScan = new Scan();
edgeScan.setFilter(fl);
ResultScanner edgeScanner = table.getScanner(edgeScan);
Result edgeResult;
logger.info("Writing edges...");
while ((edgeResult = edgeScanner.next()) != null) {
    // Some code
}
```

This code launchs this error:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: Failed after retry of OutOfOrderScannerNextException: was there a rpc timeout?
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.next(ClientScanner.java:402)
    at org.deustotech.internet.phd.framework.rdf2subdue.RDF2Subdue.writeFile(RDF2Subdue.java:150)
    at org.deustotech.internet.phd.framework.rdf2subdue.RDF2Subdue.run(RDF2Subdue.java:39)
    at org.deustotech.internet.phd.Main.main(Main.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.OutOfOrderScannerNextException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.OutOfOrderScannerNextException: Expected nextCallSeq: 1 But the nextCallSeq got from client: 0; request=scanner_id: 178 number_of_rows: 100 close_scanner: false next_call_seq: 0
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.scan(HRegionServer.java:3098)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:29497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2012)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:98)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.SimpleRpcScheduler.consumerLoop(SimpleRpcScheduler.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.SimpleRpcScheduler.access$000(SimpleRpcScheduler.java:39)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.SimpleRpcScheduler$1.run(SimpleRpcScheduler.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.getRemoteException(ProtobufUtil.java:285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:204)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.next(ClientScanner.java:354)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RemoteWithExtrasException(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.OutOfOrderScannerNextException): org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.OutOfOrderScannerNextException: Expected nextCallSeq: 1 But the nextCallSeq got from client: 0; request=scanner_id: 178 number_of_rows: 100 close_scanner: false next_call_seq: 0
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.scan(HRegionServer.java:3098)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:29497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2012)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:98)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.SimpleRpcScheduler.consumerLoop(SimpleRpcScheduler.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.SimpleRpcScheduler.access$000(SimpleRpcScheduler.java:39)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.SimpleRpcScheduler$1.run(SimpleRpcScheduler.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient.call(RpcClient.java:1453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient.callBlockingMethod(RpcClient.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(RpcClient.java:1715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$BlockingStub.scan(ClientProtos.java:29900)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:174)
    ... 13 more
```

The RPC timeout is set to 600000. I have tried to remove some filters given these results:

- sourceUpperFilter && (sourceLowerFilter || targetLowerFilter) --> Success
- targetUpperFilter && (sourceLowerFilter || targetLowerFilter) --> Success
- (sourceUpperFilter && targetUpperFilter) && (sourceLowerFilter) --> Fail
- (sourceUpperFilter && targetUpperFilter) && (targetLowerFilter) --> Fail

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Mikel, did you ever end up finding a solution to this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, not... I left HBase and I started using Hypertable...

Comment: pls change RPC time put 600000 to 1800000 please see my answer

Answer (score 2):

I solve this problem by setting `hbase.client.scanner.caching`

[see also](https://github.com/mattshma/bigdata/issues/7)

> Client and RS maintain a nextCallSeq number during the scan. Every next() call from client to server will increment this number in both sides. Client passes this number along with the request and at RS side both the incoming nextCallSeq and its nextCallSeq will be matched. In case of a timeout this increment at the client side should not happen. If at the server side fetching of next batch of data was over, there will be mismatch in the nextCallSeq number. Server will throw OutOfOrderScannerNextException and then client will reopen the scanner with startrow as the last successfully retrieved row.
>
> Since the problem is caused by the client-side overtime, then the corresponding reduction in client cache (hbase.client.scanner.caching) size or increase rpc timeout time (hbase.rpc.timeout) can be.

Hope this answer helps.

Comment: Please copy essential parts of link content here

Answer (score 0):

Reason :Looking for few rows from a big region. It takes time to fill the #rows
as requested by client side. By this time the client gets an rpc timeout.
So client side will retry the call on same scanner. Remember with this next
call client says give me next N rows from where you are. The old failed
call was in progress and would have advanced some rows. So this retry call
will miss those rows.... to avoid this and to distinguish this case we have
this scan seqno and this exception.  On seeing this  the client will close
the scanner and create a new one with proper start row . But this retry way
happens only one more time.  Again this call also might be timing out.

**So we
have to adjust the timeout and/or scan caching value.**
heart beat mechanism avoids such timeout for long running scans.

In our case where data is huge in hbase we have used 
RPC time out = 1800000 and lease period = 1800000 and we have used [fuzzy row filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37011342/scan-hbase-rows-by-ignoring-a-part-of-the-start-and-end-row-in-java)  and also  `scan.setCaching(xxxx)// value need to be adjusted ;`

Note : value filters are slow(since full table scan will take long for execution) than row filter

With all above precautions we are successful to query huge data from hbase with mapreduce.

Hope this explanation helps.