# Scan HBase rows by ignoring a part of the start and end row in Java

Tags: java, hbase

I have HBase rows as follows

```
ABC_A1_20160101
ABC_A2_20160102
ABC_A3_20160103
XYZ_A9_20160201
```

from my Java code I know first part `ABC` and last part `20160101`. There is no way I can get the middle part `A1, A2, A3....`.

***In this case how can I query in Java ?***

From `ABC_A1_20160101` To `ABC_A3_20160103`

Comment: did you find any thing? filter options at hbase shell are also same in java client code except syntax in java.

Comment: If you are okay please vote-up "accepted by owner"

Answer (score 3):

Fuzzy row approach is efficient for this kind of requirement and when data is is huge : 
As explained by this [article](https://sematext.com/blog/2012/08/09/consider-using-fuzzyrowfilter-when-in-need-for-secondary-indexes-in-hbase/)
FuzzyRowFilter takes as parameters row key and a mask info. In example above, in case we want to find last logged in users and row key format is userId_actionId_timestamp (where userId has fixed length of say 4 chars), the fuzzy row key we are looking for is “????*login*”. This translates into the following params for FuzzyRowKey:

```
FuzzyRowFilter rowFilter = new FuzzyRowFilter(
 Arrays.asList(
  new Pair<byte[], byte[]>(
    Bytes.toBytesBinary("\x00\x00\x00\x00_login_"),
    new byte[] {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0})));
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand this approach.  What is this line doing ? Bytes.toBytesBinary("\x00\x00\x00\x00_login_"),
    new byte[] {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0})));

Comment: and I want to scan b/w start and end row. if you have any example that would be greatfull.

Comment: 1) if you want to scan using start row and end row. you can set that to scan object. please refer scan class methods.                                                                            2) Fuzzy row filter works on fuzzy logic. there are 2 parts in it, which are fixed part and variable part. fixed part is the one whichyou know before hand. variable part will be filled with placeholders.                               For detailed explanation and example please refer this https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/hbase-the-definitive/9781491905845/ch04.html

Comment: was that helpful ?